AlmaLinux 8.10 VPS hostname keeps getting overwritten, probably by NetworkManager
On AlmaLinux 8.10 ....
I am trying for over 12 hours to change hostname permanently so it does not change back when I reboot. Very frustrating.
With most servers it works with hostnamectl set-hostname  new.myhost.example.com, on this one seems to work too, but it gets changed on reboot.
This is a VPS I assume this is done by the upper network configuration of my hosting provider, because they can change it fine from their end, but I want to change it myself when needed. Their reply is just "we can change it from here or Google how to change it yourself".
The below logs shows how hostname changes back when network is connected after reboot.
I think I need a variable to tell NetworkManager to stop automatically updating hostname, but I don't know what is all this mistery around the NetworkManager variables, can't find much info.

I tried DHCP_HOSTNAME=new.myhost.example.com inside these 2 files:

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-2
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0


I tried:

# inside: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

[main]
plugins=keyfile
hostname-mode=none

[keyfile]
hostname=new.myhost.example.com

Thou now I seen in log it says keyfile: 'hostname' option is deprecated and has no effect.
This is what log shows on each command:
hostnamectl set-hostname  new.myhost.example.com
Sep 15 22:09:52 new dbus-daemon[628]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.44' (uid=0 pid=1296 comm="hostnamectl set-hostname  new.myhost.example.com ")
Sep 15 22:09:52 new systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Sep 15 22:09:52 new dbus-daemon[628]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Sep 15 22:09:52 new systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Sep 15 22:09:52 new systemd-hostnamed[1297]: Changed static host name to ' new.myhost.example.com'
Sep 15 22:09:52 new NetworkManager[629]: <info>  [1726452592.3467] hostname: static hostname changed from "old.myhost.example.com" to " new.myhost.example.com"
Sep 15 22:09:52 new systemd-hostnamed[1297]: Changed host name to ' new.myhost.example.com'
Sep 15 22:09:52 new dbus-daemon[628]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.2' (uid=0 pid=629 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon ")
Sep 15 22:09:52 new systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Sep 15 22:09:52 new dbus-daemon[628]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Sep 15 22:09:52 new systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Sep 15 22:10:02 new systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.

reboot ...
Log shows how hostname changes back when network is connected !
Sep 15 22:12:15 new NetworkManager[631]: <info>  [1726452735.9600] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Sep 15 22:12:15 new NetworkManager[631]: <info>  [1726452735.9601] device (eth0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 15 22:12:15 new NetworkManager[631]: <info>  [1726452735.9604] device (eth0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 15 22:12:15 new NetworkManager[631]: <info>  [1726452735.9608] policy: set 'prl_nettool-nm-eth0' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Sep 15 22:12:15 new NetworkManager[631]: <info>  [1726452735.9624] device (eth0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 15 22:12:15 new NetworkManager[631]: <info>  [1726452735.9645] device (eth0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 15 22:12:15 new NetworkManager[631]: <info>  [1726452735.9646] device (eth0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 15 22:12:15 new NetworkManager[631]: <info>  [1726452735.9648] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Sep 15 22:12:15 new NetworkManager[631]: <info>  [1726452735.9650] device (eth0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Sep 15 22:12:15 new NetworkManager[631]: <info>  [1726452735.9653] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Sep 15 22:12:15 new chronyd[636]: Source 213.239.154.12 online
Sep 15 22:12:15 new chronyd[636]: Source 178.239.19.63 online
Sep 15 22:12:15 new chronyd[636]: Source 185.51.192.61 online
Sep 15 22:12:15 new chronyd[636]: Source 178.239.19.61 online
Sep 15 22:12:16 new systemd-hostnamed[653]: Changed static host name to 'old.myhost.example.com'
Sep 15 22:12:16 new NetworkManager[631]: <info>  [1726452736.1383] hostname: static hostname changed from "new.myhost.example.com" to "old.myhost.example.com"
Sep 15 22:12:16 new NetworkManager[631]: <info>  [1726452736.1412] policy: set-hostname: set hostname to 'old.myhost.example.com' (from system configuration)
Sep 15 22:12:16 new NetworkManager[631]: <info>  [1726452736.1413] audit: op="hostname-save" arg="old.myhost.example.com" pid=1228 uid=0 result="success"
Sep 15 22:12:16 new systemd-hostnamed[653]: Changed host name to 'old.myhost.example.com'
Sep 15 22:12:16 new qemu-ga[669]: info: guest-exec close [stdout cid=2] queue=0 total=0

The relevant config files are these in case I need to post some contents:
find /etc/NetworkManager/
/etc/NetworkManager/
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/prl_nettool-nm-eth0.nmconnection
/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d
/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d
/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/60-prl_nettool_eth0.conf
/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq-shared.d
/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d
/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/20-chrony-dhcp
/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/pre-down.d
/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/20-chrony-onoffline
/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/pre-up.d
/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/no-wait.d


Also found this bug that seems related but the commands din't help, I also tried to put that ... only-from-default ... inside NetworkManager.conf https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1766944

Can’t you set the desired name of the system in the providers control panel? As doing so will often also set up the reverse DNS record correctly.

They don't have a web interface for that and I need to open a ticket whenever I need to do it. And I kind of wanted to get to the bottom of this because I think in 8.x I always had this problem but not in any other version.

I don't see a hostname associated when I run that ip: host 123.123.123.123 but sitll I think it gets that hostname from ISP / DHCP somehow.

Log says systemd-hostnamed[653]: Changed static host name could it be that hostnamed has some config policy and NetworkManager just gets triggered by that  change?

After 3-4 days of anoying debugging and frustration, my conclusion is that this hostname change problem is a NetworkManager bug (maybe this bug) in certain configurations and versions like:
NetworkManager 1.40.16-15.el8_9 and others
AlmaLinux 8.1, seen in other 8.x too
Kernel 6.10.10, happen with old kernel 4.x too

It is also seems related to configurations that by default take hostname from DHCP.

If anyone runs into this, hostname keeps changing back to default when trying to set it by hostnamectl set-hostname new.myserver.tld, and if you have a feature to change it in your web hosting / isp web interface, go that route. Easier and reliable.

Short version

do not change it by hostnamectl, if you did, reboot before continuing
set hostname by adding kernel.hostname = new.myserver.tld in a new sysctl file /lib/sysctl.d/60-my-custom-settings.conf, (60 or whichever is next file number in that folder).
set hostname-mode=none in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf [main] section
reboot TWICE to make sure settings persist, because some commands like hostnamectl set-hostname might trigger resetting hostname to default, on first boot only (even with above kernel.hostname set) !
check with hostnamectl; it should say that transient hostname is new hostname, static hostname remains the same old one.
hostname; command shows new hostname
file /etc/hostname keeps showing OLD static value


Long version TL;DR
I wanted to get to a conclusion / solution, so below is what [kind of] worked:

do NOT use hostnamectl set-hostname your-new-hostname, if you did, restart the machine twice without changing anything yet. More details at the very end.

provide a custom kernel hostname eider in /etc/sysctl.conf OR by creating a custom file with a higher number than the other files in /lib/sysctl.d/ directory:


/lib/sysctl.d/60-my-custom-settings.conf
kernel.hostname = new.myserver.tld


edit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf and tell NetworkManager to "not manage the transient hostname and never set it" (hostname-mode=none).

[main]
hostname-mode=none

# at the very end, under logging, enable these 2, easier to debug NetworkManager messages
[logging]
level=TRACE
domains=ALL

Tip: run NetworkManager --print-config to check if you used a variable in the wrong [section] or if a variable is unknown, etc.

reboot

Results:

hostnamectl; will still show the old hostname under static hostname, but will always reliably show new.myserver.tld as Transient hostname

hostnamectl;

Static hostname: old.myserver.tld
Transient hostname: new.myserver.tld


the simple hostname; command will properly return new.myserver.tld
the file /etc/hostname will still show the old static value old.myserver.tld but it is less important, because most programs should get it from hostname command.
service systemd-hostnamed status shows the new hostname as log prefix:

[date] new.myserver.tld systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
[date] new.myserver.tld systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Succeeded.


service NetworkManager status will detect the old static old.myserver.tld (see line #1) but it should then say that hostname is unmanaged and will keep showing new hostname as a log prefix:

[date] new.myserver.tld NetworkManager[647]: <info>  audit: op="hostname-save" arg="old.myserver.tld" pid=1358 uid=0 result="success"
[date] new.myserver.tld NetworkManager[647]: <trace> policy: set-hostname: hostname is unmanaged
[date] new.myserver.tld NetworkManager[647]: <trace> device[871fb723854d0965] (eth0): remove_pending_action (0):

That was as far as I was able to get with changing hostname in this machine. If I try the normal way:
hostnamectl set-hostname new.myserver.tld

Then after restart, this machine's NetworkManager log says it detected static hostname as "none", then sets to the the old static one old.myserver.tld and then continues to use that and not the one you provided in hostnamectl set-hostname new.myserver.tld before the restart AND NOT even the one set by kernel.hostname. Same thing if I try to manually set new hostname in /etc/hostname, after restart it gets detected as none, then gets changed to the old static old.myserver.tld.
So in that situation, most reliable thing to do was: do not change it by hostnamectl, set it by kernel.hostname sysctl conf file, set hostname-mode=none in NetworkManager.conf
I even tried running hostnamectl on startup, or edit file /etc/hostname on startup, everyting fails and then gets reset to default old.myserver.tld in both static and transient hostname. To make debugging worse, trying to change hostname as startup sometimes gets trigger before or after the NetworkManager startup, then restults are random.
I said that sometimes it needs two restarts, because you might have set a correct new hostname in kernel.hostname sysctl file at #2 above, but if you also did a hostnamectl set-hostname your-new-hostname before the restart, then on first boot it will reset to default static hostname (for both static and transient hostname), and only on second restart it will take it from kernel.hostname sysctl file and use that as transient hostname.
